# HTTP Client with cookie support in Rust

Tags: http, cookies, httprequest, rust

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this or not, but I'm looking for a library that wraps HTTP requests in a client structure and includes the ability to retrieve and store cookies for individual sessions (like Python Requests library).

I'm looking to create a small bot for scraping a website and wanted to use it as an excuse to learn Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teepee, hyper, and rust-http don't seem to have cookie support.

However, khodzha has some in-progress work for adding cookie support to Servo. [This file](https://github.com/khodzha/servo/blob/d6d9f715fc3ab3e79bb69c4e159c9bac4e48445e/components/net/cookie.rs) from [his branch](https://github.com/khodzha/servo/compare/cookies) might be able to help you.

Warning: The code is a work in progress, I suggest you contact the author on IRC or github before using it.

Comment: Thanks, I had heard of the three above already but it's odd none of them support cookies. I think I'll just fork one of them and do what khodzha is doing.